# Triple integral and the Laplacian

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplacian

Set $D:=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1\}$. Denote $\Delta:= \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial z^2}$. Suppose that a $C^2$-function $\phi(x,y,z)$ vanishes in the neighborhood of $\partial D$. I want to prove that
$$\iiint_D (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}(\Delta \phi)(x,y,z)dxdydz=-4\pi\phi(0,0,0).$$
Using the spherical coordinates I can write
$$\iiint_D (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}(\Delta \phi)(x,y,z)dxdydz=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1 (\Delta \phi)(\rho\sin\varphi\cos\theta,\rho\sin\varphi\sin\theta,\rho\cos\varphi)\rho \sin \varphi d\rho d\theta d\varphi.$$
However I don't know where to use the assumption $\phi$ vanishes in the neighborhood of $\partial D$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should try to use some Gauss/Stokes at some point.

Comment: $\nabla^{2}\left(1 \over r\right) = -4\pi\,\delta\left(\vec{r}\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Green's second identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities),
$$\iiint_D (\psi\Delta\phi-\phi\Delta\psi)dV=\iint_{\partial D^+}\left(\psi\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial {\bf n}}-\phi\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial {\bf n}}\right)dS$$
with $\psi(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}$.

Note that $\Delta\psi(x,y,z)=-4\pi\delta(x,y,z)$ and the integral on the right-hand side is zero because  $\phi$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial {\bf n}}$ vanish in the neighborhood of $\partial D$.

Comment: Does the fact that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial {\bf n}}$ vanishes in the neighborhood of $\partial D$ follow from ${\partial \phi  \over \partial {\mathbf  {n}}}=\nabla \phi \cdot {\mathbf  {n}}=\nabla _{{\mathbf  {n}}}\phi$?

Comment: Yes, also $\nabla \phi=0$ on $\partial D$. That is the reason why you need $\phi=0$ in neighborhood of $\partial D$ and not simply $\phi=0$ on  $\partial D$.

Comment: So what we get from your computation is $\iiint_D \psi\Delta\phi dV=\iiint_D \phi\Delta\psi dV=-4\pi\iiint_D \phi\delta(x,y,z)dV$. How can you prove that $\iiint_D \phi\delta(x,y,z)dV=\phi(0,0,0)$?

Comment: This is a property of the 3D-delta function, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions

Comment: Which property are you mentioning to?

Comment: See the first integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Generalizations

Comment: Thanks so much. It's clear now.